# timer issue in published asp.net mvc website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6

I have a website which as published on Azure (as App Service) which was developed using ASP.NET MVC, SQL, EF6 technology stack.

I have a class inside the project which constantly pings the service bus queue for new messages.

If there is a new message in service bus queue, it should fetch the message and log into the database.

Problem is that when I published into Azure, the class is not working properly and not reading the messages always.

Is there a better solution to do that?

Comment: Does that class work properly on local?

Comment: yup, its working fine on development PC.

Comment: what message are you getting from the server?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question @JosueMartinez

Comment: So when published, it sometimes reads the service bus messages, or it never reads them? Is it working intermittently? Does it give any error messages?

Comment: OKay, when it is published, it is reading the messages only when you load a page. If no one is interacting with the website, the class is not working.
For example, if there are a whole bunch of messages sitting in the service bus for whole night and when someone opens the website in the morning, it is loading all the messages at that time and thus making wrong date time stamp.

Comment: So the timer doesn't fire unless someone is hitting the web server? If that's the case, you need another way to trigger the timer/message checking.

Comment: I am not getting any ideas for that, can you suggest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you could create a background task to listen messages from your service bus queue, then retrieve the message and save it to your database. For example, you could define `_maunalResetEvent` under `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
private static ManualResetEvent _maunalResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

And add the following code under the `Application_Start` event of the `Global.asax.cs`.

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        var connectionString = "";
        var queueName = "samplequeue";
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
        client.OnMessage(message =>
        {
            var messageBody = message.GetBody<String>();
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("Message body: {0}", messageBody));

           //TODO: save the message to the database
        });
        _maunalResetEvent.WaitOne();
    });
```

Moreover, you could use Azure Functions as Joe Wilson answered, and use [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) for event-based message handling instead of creating a timer or scheduler to manually retrieve the queue message(s). Also, you could leverage WebJobs to implement your scenario, details you could follow [How to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus).

Additionally, for hosting on Azure App service, you app would go idle after a few minutes (20 minutes by default) of inactivity. So you need to enable the **Always On** option. **Note:** You could enable **Always On** to keep your app loaded all the time in Basic or higher app service plan. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings).

Answer (score 1):

If your timer doesn't fire unless someone is hitting the web server, you need another way to trigger the timer and do the service bus checking.

You are already using Azure, so you should look into [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). It has a [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) option and can run your message checking every 5 minutes or whatever your application needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on the **Always On** of your Azure web app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure

As others mentioned, a better way is to move the logic to Azure Functions with a timer trigger, or create WebJobs. If you go with WebJobs, you still need to turn on the Always On.